# Show/hide div on click if div class names match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two sets of divs — one that is the 'main' div and one that is the 'extra' div. Both of these have classes that are brought in via the CMS.

What's the best way of showing/hiding (preferably slideToggle) each div, on click, that corresponds to the div clicked?

```
<div class="each-business-content-main" data-id="group-1"></div>
<div class="each-business-content-main" data-id="group-2"></div>
<div class="each-business-content-extra group-1"></div>
<div class="each-business-content-extra group-2"></div>
```

These 'group-1' or 'group-2' classes aren't known in advance so can't be hard-coded in. Essentially I'm wondering how, if you click on one div it shows another div (as long as they share the same class name).

I've tried this so far:

```
$('.each-business-content-main').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    jQuery('.each-business-content-extra').slideUp();
    jQuery('.each-business-content-extra .' + id).slideDown();
});
```

But I'm guessing hrefs and id might come in useful? Or some other data-id...

Comment: Cool, post some code you've tried and we'll be able to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign a data attribute to your divs it makes this pretty easy:

```
<div class="each-business-content-main group-1" data-group="1">main 1</div>
<div class="each-business-content-main group-2" data-group="2">main 2</div>
<div class="each-business-content-extra group-1" data-group="1">extra 1</div>
<div class="each-business-content-extra group-2" data-group="2">extra 2</div>
$('.each-business-content-main').click(function () {
    $('.each-business-content-extra.group-' + $(this).data('group')).slideToggle();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yrUN9/1/)**

Comment: Can you add more than a letter or number to data-group? I have this and it doesn't work...

`<div class="each-business-content-main" data-group="fish-group"></div>
<div class="each-business-content-extra" data-group="fish-group" style="display:none;"></div>`

Comment: Absolutely. I just chose that since I'm lazy ;) The HTML would then be `data-group="fish"` and the jQuery would need a tweak. `$('.each-business-content-extra.group-' + $(this).data('group'))`would then be `$('.each-business-content-extra.'+$(this).data('group')+'-group')`

Comment: Ah right, sorry... but there's no 'group' as the next set of divs have the group 'benchmark-vaccines-ltd' — can we use data-ids instead?

Comment: Yes, ideal. Is there any way so if another div is clicked, the open div closes and the clicked div opens?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing this:

```
jQuery('.each-business-content .' + id).slideDown();
```

...with this:

```
jQuery('.each-business-content #' + id).slideDown();
```

jQuery selects classnames as `.classname` and IDs as `#id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.each-business-content').click(function () {
  var that = $(this);
  $('.each-business-content').each(function () {
    if ($(this) === that) {
      $(this).slideUp();
    } else {
      $(this).slideDown();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this [code at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehBMs/2/)? Don't need group 1 and group 2, I use index instead of the name of the id. Is that all right for you?

```
$('.each-business-content-main').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.each-business-content-extra').(':eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').slideDown();
    $('.each-business-content-extra').not(':eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').slideUp();
});
```